# Symfony2 how to persist an integer and then reference an entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, relationships

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this as it's driving me crazy.

I have a form which allows a user to add a Pet and contains select boxes for species and breed. These fields are in the pet table as integers which are required in order to list the data in a CMS and I do that by linking the ids with the respective entites, like so:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Species", inversedBy="pet", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="species", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $species;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Breed", inversedBy="pet", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="breed", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $breed;
```

The "species" table contains an Id, name and description as does the "breed" table. The "pet" table simply contains columns called "species" and "breed" which are integers. However, when the form is submitted I get the following Symfony error:

> Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association AppBundle\Entity\Pet#species, but expecting AppBundle\Entity\Species

But - if I change the @var to the entity of Species (or Breed for $breed) I cannot list the Pets in the CMS as I get this error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a string variable ("1") in AppBundle:tables:petstable.html.twig at line 39

I am assigning it in the list page as follows:

```
<tbody>
          {% for pet in pets %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ pet.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ pet.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ pet.species.name|title }}</td>
            <td>{{ pet.breed.name|title }}</td>
            <td>{{ pet.dateAdded|date('Y-m-d')}}</td>
            <td>{% for owner in pet.customer %}
                <a href="{{ path('app_customers_profile', {'id':owner.id}) }}">
                  {{ (owner.firstname ~ ' ' ~ owner.lastname ~ ' ')|e }}
                </a>
                {% else %}
                  No owners found
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-owner" data-id="{{ pet.id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bs_modal_small"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ path('app_pet_edit',  {'id':pet.id}) }}">Edit</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
            {% else %}
            <td colspan="8">No pets found with given filters, please try another filter.</td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Line 39 which the error refers to is this:

```
<td>{{ pet.species.name|title }}</td>
```

This will also happen on line 40 as it cannot access the attribute "name" on breed either.

Any help appreciated - this is really causing me a headache and I just cannot get my head around it!

If there is another thread that has a solution to this problem which maybe I just haven't found, any linkage to that would be great too.

Thank you in advance
Michael

Comment: `@var` is a phpDocumentator tag. It's not related to Doctrine. Doctrine ignores it. Your errors are somewhat related to `@var`, but not because of Doctrine. Can you please remove the `@var` annotation at all and see what happens?

Comment: Oh, just noticed "when the form is submitted" - can you please post the related snippet?

Comment: where's form code? where's controller code for form handling?

Comment: Actually, I think I may have fixed it this morning - however, it only seems to work if I use the "multiple => 'true'" attribute in the FormType.php code. Seems strange but I guess I can work with it.. thanks